# Data imported to Samsung Health doesn't show in the app, but they are imported to HealthDataStorage

Tags: android, fitbit, samsung-health

I'm just copying [my question from Samsung Developers portal](https://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=367731&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000032) as I had no resonses from them for 2 days.

I've imported 3 years worth step counter data from FitBit to [Samsung Health](https://www.samsung.com/uk/apps/samsung-health/) via [Samsung API](https://developer.samsung.com/health).

I can see they are there, in Samsung's storage, when I query API from my app or [Samsung's Data Viewer app](https://developer.samsung.com/health/android/data/guide/dataviewer) (when I manage to get it working).

However in the Health app itself I can only see the data which are about month old. But to make it even weirder - that month old data - I managed to upload them, but I couldn't get them deleted from the app. At least not visually, because physically they did get deleted and re-uploaded again.

To add more to all this - after the 3 year worth of data upload the app became very sluggish and drained my phone's battery in half day, because it was doing something in the background. After 1 day I've reinstalled the app and now it doesn't drain the battery, but imported step count data are still not showing.

Adding/removing steps for current day shows pretty much instantly in the app, so it's not the problem with the method, but more like with the volume and the age of the data. I've imported these 3 year data on a minute basis.

---

Right, so today, or more specifically after something like 24 hours - my imported data are gone from the HealthDataStore... 
Will try again - don't you worry, Samsung...

FitBit data for the last 3 months are in HealthDataStore now. Visible both from Data Viewer and from my app via Samsung Health API. Doesn't appear in Samsung Health app again. Some phantom numbers from 17th of March until 8th of April (when I got my Galaxy Watch) are still in Samsung Health app and remains there despite me adding or removing data for those days. They only shows when 'All steps' option is picked up, but doesn't show when I choose individual devices (phone, watch or unknown0). Please see below - Samsung Health app shows data that's been/ supposed to be deleted:

[image]

Data Viewer app shows data that are updated, however they are not shown in Samsung Health app:

[image]

And here, in my app, I can query any of uploaded date too, but it's not visible in Samsung Health app:

[image]

---

Added weight records for the last 3 years from FitBit today - no problems with those - comes up on Samsung Health up within a seconds.

The steps that were previously gone/deleted from SamsungHealthStorage are now visible again via my app and Data Viewer app, but not via Samsung Health app. So basically these data got restored somehow. What is going on?..

---

Adding Heart Rate data does also work fine. So the problems remains with Step Counter data - no visual appearance in Samsung Health app - only in SamsungHealthStorage.